# Convert uint64_t to int64_t generically for all data widths

Tags: c++

How does one generically convert signed and unsigned integers into each other without having to specify the specific width?

For example:

```
uint8_t <-> int8_t
uint16_t <-> int16_t
uint32_t <-> int32_t
uint64_t <-> int64_t
```

It would be nice to write:

```cpp
uint32_t x;
int32_t y;
static_cast<signed>(x)
static_cast<unsigned>(y)
```

However, I suspect that doesn't do what I want.

I think I can achieve a similar effect using this method but I would think doing it for the same data width might have some syntactic sugar.

[Conditional template type math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63433188/conditional-template-type-math)

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/make_signed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *However, I suspect that doesn't do what I want.*

Indeed, your suspicion is valid: the expression, `static_cast<signed>(x)`, is *exactly* equivalent to `static_cast<signed int>(x)`, so the cast will *always* be to an object of the 'default' size of an `int` on the given platform (and, similarly, `unsigned` is equivalent to `unsigned int`).

---

However, with a little bit of work, you can create 'generic' cast template functions that use the [`std::make_signed`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/make_signed) and [`std::make_unsigned`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/make_unsigned) type-trait structures.

Here's a possible implementation of such functions, with a brief test program that shows some deduced result types for different input type widths:

```cpp
#include <type_traits> // For make_signed and make_unsigned

template<typename T>
static inline auto unsigned_cast(T s)
{
    return static_cast<std::make_unsigned<T>::type>(s);
}

template<typename T>
static inline auto signed_cast(T s)
{
    return static_cast<std::make_signed<T>::type>(s);
}


#include <typeinfo>    // For "typeid"
#include <iostream>    

int main()
{
    int16_t s16 = 42;
    auto u16 = unsigned_cast(s16);
    std::cout << "Type of unsigned cast is: " << typeid(u16).name() << "\n";

    uint64_t u64 = 39uLL;
    auto s64 = signed_cast(u64);
    std::cout << "Type of signed cast is: " << typeid(s64).name() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```